# Structure that contains vectors with different sizes, cpp

Tags: c++, struct

I wish to declare a structure, say with size n=10, that in each i site of the structure there is a vector. The vectors in the sites of the structure have different sizes.

In matlab it can be obtained using struct. how it is done in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is an array, or a vector, of vectors.

For example:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    std::array<std::vector<int>, 10> Vectors;

    for (auto &i : Vectors)    //Loop through all 10 vectors in Vectors
    {
        for (int j=0; j<5; j++) //Push 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 into each vector
        {
            i.push_back(j);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid using numerical for loops. If you have an `std::array`, you can use range-for easily.

Comment: `vector` of what? You must specify the template type. In your case, `vector<int>`.

Comment: @FabioTurati53 Oh, yeah, sort of forgot that... :( Thanks!

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Here I used a numerical loop because it sounded like OP might not have gotten to range based loops yet (obviously just a guess on my part), but I suppose there's no time like the present to learn! :)  So I can change it if needed.

Comment: @Numeri Thanks, that works! can you help and write how do you declare it properly for 3D, where only one dimension size is unknown?

Comment: @jarhead Wrap it into another `std::array`: `std::array<std::array<std::vector<int>, 10>,10>`.

Comment: @Numeri and why would you assume that someone doesn't know range-for, but knows the more advanced and complicated numeric for?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Because that is what people are usually taught first (and I agree that that is backwards of what it should be).  Unfortunately tutorials and classes do not change quickly to match modern coding.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Though I suppose that's a very convincing argument for *me* to make sure that *my* answers aren't using old methods! I'll switch it.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct S {
    std::array<std::vector<int>, 10> data;
};
```

You can also use an alias as well:

```
using arrayOfTenVectors = std::array<std::vector<int>, 10>;
```

Of course `int` is a placeholder. You can make either the struct or the alias a `template` and use some `T` inside of the vector.

Comment: I think the OP didn't mean he wanted a C++ `struct`; rather, it was a generic term for "data structure". In this case an array of vectors, with no need to put it into a C++ `struct`. `std::vector<int> data[10];` should be enough. Of course, I might also have misinterpreted the question, but if I had to guess, I'd go for this.

Comment: @FabioTurati I've mentioned that in the second part of my answer. Besides, using C arrays doesn't have any advantage over C++ `std::array` and thus should be avoided.